# What's best practice when deleting unneccessary includes?

Tags: c++, include, readability

I have this situation in File.h:

```
//File.h
#include "Info.h"
#include "Constants.h"
```

Info.h already has Constants.h included

```
//Info.h
#include "Constants.h"
```

But File.h makes direct use of things that have been defined in Constants.h

Everything is pragma protected, so the files won't be included twice.

Should I keep the

```
//File.h
#include "Constants.h"
```

in File.h for readability, or remove it because it's already included in Info.h?

Comment: I'd directly include every header that that the including file needs, whether or not it's also included indirectly. That way, it won't break if `"Info.h"` loses its dependence on `"Constants.h"`. But it's a matter of opinion really.

Comment: Keep what you need. You shouldn't rely on indirect includes, unless a header promises to include another for ever and ever.

Comment: Would keep for readability. I believe stdlib has a similar policy, when files in the std lib include each other, it still recommends you include all, this ensures that your code doesnt break if the std lib stops including that file

Comment: Thanks, will keep it, then. :)

Comment: Headers should contain an *include guard*, that makes sure that the declarations is not included more than once, regardless if there are references from multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** rely on another header including what you need but explicitly including the headers you need.

Especially: try to move the includes into the cpp files (not into the headers) in order to minimize translation units recompilations after changes.

Avoiding including stuff through a chain of other includes paves the way for less errors and problems during maintainability and code-maintenance tasks.

---

References: many commercial-scope products agree with this philosophy, [including LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#include-as-little-as-possible).

Other than that, it's up to you.

Comment: What about precompiled headers? Precompiled headers will also decrease compilation time.

Comment: They can surely help, anyway try to minimize dependencies between modules (if possible) more than rely on speed-up techniques. This is far too broad to be addressed with a one-rule-applies-to-all sentence